# Is there any function to fix the returned value of a math calculation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing this math which is (a - b) / a = number but javascript doesn't return the correct value

Here is my code

```
6200000 - 5800000 / 6200000
```

it should return 0.06451 but it returns

```
5799998.931034483
```

How can I get only 0.06 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use brackets

`(6200000 - 5800000) / 6200000`

division happens before subtraction .. to avoid it , use brackets

if you want two digits in decimal use
`((6200000 - 5800000) / 6200000).toFixed(2)`

Comment: Thanks it worked but now it returns a negative before the value .

Comment: can you share what you are typing ?

Comment: ((6200000 - 5800000) / 6200000).toFixed(2) returns me -0.03%

Comment: can you print product.price and product.offPrice separately . if product.price is smaller result has to be negative

Comment: the above expression gives positive to me `((6200000 - 5800000) / 6200000).toFixed(2)`

Comment: awesome .. enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Try using parenthesis to evaluate the subtraction first and [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```js
var n = ((6200000 - 5800000) / 6200000).toFixed(2);
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

((6200000 - 5800000) / 6200000).toFixed(2)

Answer (score 0):

Order of math operations.

It'll run the divison before the subtraction.

To increase the order of the subtraction you can stick it in brackets.

`(6200000 - 5800000) / 6200000`

To shrink it to 2 decimal places add a `toFixed` function.

`((6200000 - 5800000) / 6200000).toFixed(2)`